# "Lo Plog" in Shas

Tags: sources-mekorot, derabanan

In a case of a gezera or any other issur that might not apply to a particular person (for whatever reason) we often still say it does because of a "lo plog". In order that we shouldn't make differences and exceptions in a gezera that was made or in a case of a particular issur.

What is an example of a "lo plog" from Shas?

What is an example of a case where we should apply the rule of a "lo plog" however we don't?

(I have not provided any examples in my question because that's exactly what I'm looking for a "classic" example that is found in Shas. As well as an example where we find that really we should say "lo plog" but we don't.)

Comment: I believe the phrase you are looking for is "לא פלוג רבנן", or "_lo palug rabanan_" - our rabbis do not differentiate. _Yad Malachi_ כללי הש"ס 'ל' כלל שנז [considers](http://books.google.com/books?id=2ItCAAAAcAAJ&lpg=RA3-PA29&ots=izYinaJN81&dq=%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%9F&pg=RA3-PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false) _Eruvin_ 65b to be a classic example.

Comment: @WAF why not make this an answer?

Comment: I didn't think it had enough substance to it, but here I go. . .

Comment: @WAF you're right, I made that commment pretty quick after seeing yours... Any others?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the phrase you are looking for is "לא פלוג רבנן", or "*lo palug rabanan*" - our rabbis do not differentiate. Yad Malachi כללי הש"ס 'ל' כלל שנז [considers](http://books.google.com/books?id=2ItCAAAAcAAJ&lpg=RA3-PA29&ots=izYinaJN81&dq=%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%9F&pg=RA3-PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false) Eruvin 65b to be a classic example.

Answer (score -1):

See Tosfos (hacha)in shabbas 45b about using an animal for a baby.

Comment: That case is a lo plug.It is not clear what type of lo plug you want?

Comment: Summarizing this would be helpful.